# Custom MessageBox Through Synchronization Context - Cannot Access Disposed Object

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, synchronizationcontext

I am in a fairly odd situation here. I have created a custom MessageBox form (instead of the built-in `MessageBox.Show`). The below code is what I use to call up the form, when I need it:

```
    internal DialogResult ShowCustomMessageBox(string message, string caption, Icon icon = null)
    {
        var result = DialogResult.None;
        MainForm.Get.UISynchContext.Send(s =>
        {
            var messageBox = new DialogBox
            {
                Icon = icon,
                Text = caption,
                rtbInDialogBox = { Text = message }
            };
            result = messageBox.ShowDialog();
            messageBox.Dispose();
        }, null);
        return result;
    }
```

When I run this, I get an error message on `messageBox.ShowDialog();` that the messageBox instance has already been disposed.

When I post the code to the synchronization context I was pretty sure MainForm would run the code itself (as opposed to other threads), and I am not sure why it tells me that the messageBox has already been disposed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. Apparently you need to specify the owner of the dialog box: `result = messageBox.ShowDialog(MainForm.Get);`